# php arrays: how to print only array values but not keys

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist

This code loops through a mysql table and prints out empty/null fields. It however prints the array values and the keys like this

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Field "dob" on entry "1" is empty/null 
    [1] => Field "user_name" on entry "7" is empty/null
)
```

How do I print something like this `field "dob" on entry "1" is empty/null`

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM userinfo";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    foreach($row as $key => $field) {
        if(empty($field)) {
            $emptyFields[] = sprintf('Field "%s" on entry "%d" is empty/null', $key,   $row['userid']);
         }
     }
}
print_r($emptyFields);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
echo implode('<br>', $emptyFields);
```

Comment: it worked fine. It prints out Field "4" on entry "11" is empty/null
Field "address" on entry "11" is empty/null. They are all the same. How do i avoid printing field "4" on entry "11" is empty/null.

Comment: I dont understand what do you need. You want to skip integer keys, am I right? Just use check `if( ! is_integer($key) AND empty($field))`.

Comment: How do i avoid printing column headers repeatedly? eg. Field "name" on column "2" is empty, Field "name" on column "3" is empty. I just wanna print one field "name" and give details rather on a separate page.

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are using print_r to output that array. So the output is formatted readable for humans.
To make it more pretty try to iterate through it like you did before with that field:

```
foreach($emptyFields as $key => $field) {
echo('Field "'.$field.'" on entry "'.$emptyField['userid'].'" is empty/null');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM userinfo";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
  foreach($row as $key => $field) {
    if(empty($field)) {
      $emptyFields[] = sprintf('Field "%s" on entry "%d" is empty/null', $key,  $row['userid']);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i dont know if I get this correctly but I think the solution to your problem is:

change the last line to:

```
$emptyFields[] = sprintf('Field "%s" on entry "%d" is empty/null', $field, $row['userid']);}}}print_r($emptyFields);
```